# How Do You Create A User Account In A podman Image?

Tags: podman

I'm new to docker/podman.  I'm able to create base images, and put things in them (i.e. java, mongodb, etc.), and get them to run.   But for the life of me, I can't seem to be able to create a user account in a podman image.  I've searched high and low on google, and that's why I'm here.

**system/platform:**

```
centos8
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM fedora:latest 
RUN useradd --uid 1000 --user-group -s /bin/bash stress
USER stress
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"] nter code here
```

**Command:**

```
[stress@localhost PodmanImages]$ podman build .
STEP 1: FROM fedora:latest
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 00c5bb959822 done
Copying config 8c2e0da7c4 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2: RUN useradd --uid 1000 --user-group -s /bin/bash stress
useradd: /etc/passwd.1: lock file already used
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
Error: error building at STEP "RUN useradd --uid 1000 --user-group -s /bin/bash stress": 
error while running runtime: exit status 1
```

I get the same error when I actually go into a container created from the image and try to run the useradd command.

```
[stress@localhost PodmanImages]$ podman run --rm --name game -it 
registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora /bin/bash
[root@c43c5df75db6 /]# useradd --uid 1000 --user-group -s /bin/bash stress
useradd: /etc/passwd.20: lock file already used
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
[root@c43c5df75db6 /]# exit
exit
[stress@localhost PodmanImages]$
```

I've removed the lock file that was created in the container, and tried to run the useradd command again, but it keeps presenting the same error.

If someone would be able to shed some light on this fore me, I've be very happy!

Thanks so much for your consideration!

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/containers/fuse-overlayfs/issues/183) in **fuse-overlayfs** that has now been fixed,
but the bugfix has not made it into Centos 8 yet.

As a workaround, you could add the command line option `--storage-driver=vfs` as the first command line argument to podman. For instance

`podman --storage-driver=vfs build .`

That solution worked for me on Centos 8.